# How can I update all the data in a database specified by selected rows in Asp GridView with a button located outside of the GridView?

Tags: asp.net, checkbox, gridview

I looked for some similar questions, but found only `ListView` solutions

But I have a `GridView` and a button outside of the `GridView` and need to udate only records specified by a selected checkbox.

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvData"
  runat="server" Width = "850px"
  CellPadding="5"
  AutoGenerateColumns="false"
  AllowPaging ="true"
  OnPageIndexChanging ="OnPaging" PageSize="5"> 
    <HeaderStyle CssClass="HeaderStyle" />
    <PagerStyle CssClass="HeaderStyle" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
    <AlternatingRowStyle CssClass="AlternatingRowStyle" />
    <RowStyle CssClass="RowStyle" />
    <RowStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" />
 <Columns>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Id" ItemStyle-Width="20px" Visible="false">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID="lblId" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("id") %>'></asp:Label>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Select" ItemStyle-Width="20px">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:CheckBox ID="chkSelect" runat="server" Checked = "false"></asp:CheckBox>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Message" ItemStyle-Width="200px">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID="lblMessage" runat="server"  Width="500px" Text='<%# Eval("Message") %>'></asp:Label>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
  </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
<br />

<div style="text-align:left;">
   <asp:Button ID="btnChange" runat="server" Text="Change Type" OnClick="btnChange_Click" />
</div>
```

I have a method `btnChange_Click()`:

```
protected void btnChange_Click()
{

    int index = gvFailedMerchants.SelectedRow.RowIndex;

    DbConnection.UpdateMessageType(index);

}
```

When I click the button, I'm getting the message

> "Object reference not set to an instance of an object"

I want to write a logic that where I traverse the grid and add ids of the selected row into one string where all ids are separated by commas:

```
1,2,3,4,5
```

Then I will send this string to the stored procedure and use them in a query within `IN` close:

```
UPDATE MYTABLE SET column = myValue WHERE ID IN('1,2,3,4,5')
```

I do not know what is the right approach to the problem.

How can I do that?

Comment: Which line throws the exception ? Have you tried putting a break point on the first line and stepping into the code ?

Comment: I know where the exception is thrown. I just do not know of the way how to implement what I need

Answer (score 0):

```
Please try this,
 <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Select" ItemStyle-Width="20px">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:CheckBox ID="chkSelect" runat="server" Checked = "false"  
         OnCheckedChanged="ChkSelect_CheckedChanged" data-id='<%# Eval("id") %>'></asp:CheckBox>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>

  protected void ChkSelect_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        CheckBox chkSel = sender as CheckBox;
        string id= chkSel.Attributes["data-id"].ToString();

        if (chkSel.Checked == true)
        {
            Session["ID"] += (Session["ID"].ToString() == "" ? id: "," + id);
        }
        else
        {
          string existingCodes = Session["ID"].ToString();
           Session["ID"] = existingCodes.Replace(id, "");               
       }
protected void btnChange_Click()
 {
    string ids =  Session["ID"].ToString();
    DbConnection.UpdateMessageType(ids);
  }
```

Comment: I'll try that, thank's. But can I do that with a List instead of session?

Comment: Declare that list variable globally in that page. Otherwise use hidden variable.